# how can I make a shortcut key for windows specific settings?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, settings

I use a dual desktop monitor but not all the time. like when I'm working I use both of the monitors by extending them, when I'm gaming I use only the main monitor. now each time I had to go to the settings, then display, then multiple displays there I had to on and off the other display.

Is there any way so that I can create a shortcut or hotkey to do these changes automatically???

Answer (score 0):

For change display settings use Windows + P shortcut